# To wget as New User without sudo in Raspbian

Tags: permissions, sudo, raspbian

I have a new user `masi` in Raspbian Jessie. I want that it has access to `/usr/bin/` etc `wget`. I did

```
sudo adduser masi     

sudo visudo
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
masi    ALL= NOPASSWD: ALL % passwordless root access

su masi
passwd
```

As `masi`, I cannot do `wget` getting `Permission denied`, only as `sudo wget` now. The command `ls -la /usr/bin/` gives user/group as `root:root` for all commands which is the problem. I think I should have `root:wheel`. I think this can be done by

```
groupadd wheel
sudo usermod -a -G wheel masi
sudo chown root:wheel /usr/bin/*
```

I took the groupname `wheel` from my OS X. I am not sure if it is the right convention here for naming. 
I do not understand how Raspbian Jessie has beed designed. I only understand little Ubuntu.

I think the commands may not be sufficient because the thing is changing only one directory. I am setting up `owncloud` server with PostgeSQL-9.4 in Raspian as described [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0FBjZoAfHgg) for older version.

---

How can you add a new user with sufficient righs for `wget` and others in working folders /usr/bin/ ... in Raspbian?

Comment: could you clarify whether you want user `masi` to have write access in `/usr/bin` directory, and add the output of `wget` to your original post?

Comment: @adonis Clarified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You able to set

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/*
```

It's a little strangely that files in `bin` are not executable be default.

For example in my ubuntu:

`$ ls -la /usr/bin/
...
rwxr-xr-x  1 root root         14768 апр 15 01:19 zdump
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root         10384 янв 31 02:14 zeisstopnm
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root        206000 фев 24 17:31 zeitgeist-daemon
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root        131760 фев 24 17:31 zeitgeist-datahub
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root        105752 фев 16 18:30 zenity
...`